# encapsular campo de gridview en Textbox al filtrar asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un formulario con un dropdownlist y un textbox , cuando selecciono un item en el dropdownlist este me filtra la información y me trae una fecha la cual quiero que se muestre también en el textbox , estoy haciendo la ejecución en el evento RowDatabound. espero me puedan ayudar

```
protected void GvSp_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e){
    txtFecha.Text = GvSp.Rows[0].Cells[3].Text;
}
```

Comment: Pero cual es tu problema? Tenes alguna excepción?

Comment: No entiendo que quieres conseguir, el evento RowDataBound se ejecuta por cada dato bindeado al grid, tomar el valor de la primer row no veo para que sirve. Si necesitas seleccionar una row en concreto debes usar el evento RowCommand para eso debes definir un link o boton en una columna del grid